# Classify Signals (Static vs Dynamic) Homework Assignment

Tags: homework, signal-theory

For the following assignment, I only want to see if I am on the right path when answering the question.

The following question ask:
let x(t) be the system input and y(t) be the system output. Determine whether the system is static vs. dynamic and causal vs. non-causal.

1) y(t) = 2x(t-1) + 4x(t-2) + 3x(t)

2) y(t) = 10\$x^2\$(t)

I started off by plugging t = 0 in equation 1, which results in:

y(0) = 2x(-1) + 4x(-2) + 3x(0)

From this the first two terms on the left side of the equation depends on past inputs. For this reason, I believe the system is dynamic and casual as the output depends on the past and present inputs.

For the second problem, I also plugged in t for 0 for:

y(0) = 10\$x^2\$(0)
I believe this is static and casual(output depends on only the present value).

Comment: This isn't an electrical engineering question.

Comment: I think you are on the right track. I am not sure what "dynamic" means, though. Maybe it just means that the output depends on the input? But I think your understanding of causal is correct.

Comment: http://myclassbook.org/static-dynamic-systems/ and http://myclassbook.org/causal-noncausal-system-causality-property/ should sort you out

Comment: @winny signals and systems is core curriculum for some branches of electrical engineering (I had two semesters of it during my degree)

Comment: @vicaucu Sure thing, so did I. Still, there is math.SE.

Comment: +1 for honest designation of your question as "homework".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- A system is static iff the output at time t depends only on the input at time t
- A system is dynamic iff the output at time t depends on the input at time t as well as the input at other times (i.e. in the past or future)
- A system is causal iff the output at time t depends only on the the input at times at or before time t (i.e. not future values of the input)
- A system is anti-causal if its output depends on the input at times after time t.